# SoapClient not found alternative solution

Tags: php, soap

i have to integrate my site with a soap webservice. I see that my host doesn't accept soap

```
Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found
```

so i need alternatives to use soap in any case.
Does anyone know a solution? thansk!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this [NuSOAP - SOAP Toolkit for PHP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/), but you may have to change a little of code, the api is not complete same with the native SoapClient of PHP. You may consider update your PHP version.

Comment: is the same as using soapClient?

Comment: php is updated, the hosting company disable soap.. so if i want to list all function of my webservice? is possible with NuSOAP?

Comment: It is a set of PHP classes - no PHP extensions required - that allow developers to create and consume web services based on SOAP 1.1, WSDL 1.1 and HTTP 1.0/1.1.

Comment: ok i see it. do you know how to get the list of ws's functions?